# How to Copy Yes/No field data in Sharepoint list to Sharepoint list using SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I am copying sharepoint list data using SSIS package and they are copying perfectly.
But the problem is when there is a Choice field or Yes/No field at that time it is copying only default value to destination no matter which value is there in source.
So, Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi Stark, I've developed a SSIS package in SQL 2008 R2 that is pulling SharePoint list date based on the Site List Name, Site List View Name (optional), and Site URL.  It has no problem pulling all of the data, including those that are binary (yes/no), and sending the data to a database table.  Can you provide a little more information about how you are pulling the SharePoint list data and where it is being sent?  With that information, perhaps I can be of assistance.  Thanks.

Comment: i am copying data of the list in the same list using sharepointlist source to sharepoint list destination but the problem is that it is taking default value in yes/no field.

Comment: Are you using the SharePoint list adapter from CodePlex?  If so, what version?

Comment: yes... i am using SharePoint list adapter from CodePlex....